# Teradata SQL VARCHAR and spaces

Tags: sql, database, teradata, varchar, sqldatatypes

I dont quite follow when I do a plain insert of numeric data into a varchar 
field why does it  Left pad it with 2 spaces . Is not varchar supposed to trim off spaces ( trailing ok...but where is the rule that you "frontpad" with spaces)  . Why then pad with 2 leading spaces

```
INSERT INTO v VALUES  ( ,1243444,3455435,8768810,'fdff',5,7,8,,)
```

Here `( ,1243444,3455435,8768810,'fdff',5,7,8,,)` are `(someirrelvant_datatype,varchar(x),varchar(y),varchar(z),char(5),smallint,int,int,Timestamp)`

So data looks like this

```
SEL     CHAR2HEXINT  ( colA ) ,colA FROM v


313732353732    172572  /* this is some other pre-existing value*/ 
2020202033343535343335      3455435  /* this is value just inserted */
```

So if you see above `20202020` Hex for `2 spaces aka '  '`

2nd Question ( not continuation of above situation ) 
Also I have data for a varchar (50 ) col like this

```
HMSA
232434343
HMSA
4343434343
434343434
```

Here the `HMSA` has a trailing space `2020 HEX` but other values do not have `trailing spaces`. Not sure whats going on. Now here isn't `varchar` supposed to throw away all trailing spaces ? how come data landed with  `HMSA<space>`
Not sure . Any ideas ?

Ok so lets look at some oddities coming from this :

```
insert ( 'yada    ') into tb /* tb is volatile &  SET.There are 4 spaces */
insert ( 'yada') into tb 

Query Failed. 2802:  Duplicate row error in tb
```

Alright seeing what this looks like

```
7961646120202020 yada  /*There are 4 spaces  - 20 x 4 */
```

So on the 2nd insert it threw off the space comparison part and did a `trim(oldvalue) vs trim ( new value )`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Q1: When you run a `SELECT FORMAT(3455435), TYPE(3455435)` you get `-(10)9`  `INTEGER`

Every datatype always got a Cobol-style format used for casting to and from a string. In your case the datatypes of source and target didn't match and Teradata did an automatic type cast. The Format of an Integer is up to ten digits plus a leading sign *right aligend*.

Explixit type cast using Standard SQL `CAST` apply no format and thus no leading spaces. So simply do `CAST(3455435 AS VARCHAR(20)` or (TRIM(3455435)` instead.

Q2: A VarChar stores exactly what you insert, i.e. `'1234  '` will be stored including two spaces. And based on Standard SQL comparison rules trailing spaces are ignored when comparing strings, thus `'yada    '` and `'yada'` are considered equal (you probably worked with Oracle before which doesn't follow Standard SQL in this case).

Comment: Thanks.... Dieter as always, a wonderful in explanation and 'new news'  on so many common place  things happening in the db  world. Hopefully many  will  find this valuable q & a    useful